# boost::filesystem::path causing memory difference

Tags: c++, unit-testing, memory-leaks

We have several unit tests which use the Win32 `_CrtMemCheckpoint`/`_CrtMemDifference` methods to detect memory leaks in the code under test. On x64 machines (Windows 7) some of these tests report memory leaks which are not reported on x86 (32 bit) machines. On these x64 machines, compiling the following code with either VS2008 or VS2012 and using Boost 1.52.0, the result is "Memory leak detected!":

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    _CrtMemState state1, state2, state3;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);

    {
        boost::filesystem::path remoteDirPath("c:/");
    }

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);

    int res = _CrtMemDifference( &state3, &state1, &state2);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  
        std::cout << "Memory leak detected!";
    }
}
```

Is this actually a memory leak in boost::filesystem::path? I guess it's some library initalization or so, because

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    {
        boost::filesystem::path initDummy("c:/");
    }
    _CrtMemState state1, state2, state3;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);

    {
        boost::filesystem::path remoteDirPath("c:/");
    }

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);

    int res = _CrtMemDifference( &state3, &state1, &state2);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  
        std::cout << "Memory leak detected!";
    }
}
```

does NOT output "Memory leak detected!".

My question is: How can I avoid such problems with unit tests? Is initializing such a variable before starting the test a solution? Will I have to do many more such things when using other code? Or is it a bad idea in general to do such tests?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to your second code sample, I would say that boost::filesystem::path is initializing some static internal state (which remains allocated until the end of your program).

> How can I avoid such problems with unit tests?

Create a test initialization method that you execute before getting the first memory checkpoint.

Ideally you should be able to customize allocation and deallocation to track (override new/delete, add your custom allocator and so on) but that is more difficult and may not be allowed to do it, depending on the libraries you use.

> Is initializing such a variable before starting the test a solution?

It's a workaround. Not very elegant, but in the end, it is telling you what you want to know.

> Will I have to do many more such things when using other code?

Depends on what libraries you are using and how flexible they are. If you are testing code you own completely, you should consider either using an allocator type internally (a std::allocator that you can customize to track allocations), customizing new and delete or writing some allocation API that you can provide multiple implementations for.

You could also use test code that does not explicitly rely on _CrtMem* Windows APIs (boost::test library has a runtime parameter to detect memory leaks so you don't have to actually implement it yourself, but I don't know what it is doing under the hood in Win64.